# Unable to override net.Socket.write

Tags: node.js

I can't seem to override net.Socket.write. The example below is not my real use case, but rather a scaled down, runnable example to demonstrate the issue.

```
const net = require("net");

class UTF8Socket extends net.Socket {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.setEncoding("utf8");
    }

    write(data, cb) {
        console.log("Sending...");
        super.write(data, "utf8", cb);
    }

    end(data) {
        console.log("Ending socket...");
        super.end(data);
    }
}

// Setup server
const server = net.createServer(socket => {
    socket.setEncoding("utf8");
    socket.on("data", (res) => console.log("Server received data:", res));
});
server.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');

// Create a UTF8Socket and write to server
const socket = new UTF8Socket();
socket.connect(8080, "127.0.0.1", () => {
    socket.write("test write\n");
    socket.end("test end");
});
```

**Expected output:**

> Sending...
>
> Ending socket...
>
> Server received data: test write
>
> test end

**Actual output:**

> Ending socket...
>
> Server received data: test write
>
> test end

The overridden end function is called as you can see from the output, but only the original net.Socket.write is ever called. I feel like I'm missing something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's because [of this code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/d71718db6aa4feb8dc10edbad1134472468e971a/lib/net.js#L957-L958) in the implementation of `net.Socket.connect()`:

```
if (this.write !== Socket.prototype.write)
  this.write = Socket.prototype.write;
```

Possible workaround:

```
connect() {
  let result = super.connect.apply(this, arguments);
  this.write = UTF8Socket.prototype.write.bind(this);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Thanks!